# HTML proper use of labels with radio buttons needing unique IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, radio-button

I have a form that is generating the following error on multiple RADIO button sections:

`The label's "for" attribute doesn't match any element "id".  This might prevent the browser from correctly auto-filling the form and accessibility tools from working correctly'`

I realize all of the error messages are associated with RADIO buttons in the below format.  In this example, the input ids `ceSiteBanner1` and `ceSiteBanner0` are what is generating the error because neither ID match the `label for='ceSiteBanner'`:

But for JS purposes I need different IDs for each Radio button/value to change/manipulate these fields based on other form elements being filled out.  In other inputs, if a user selects a particular option, I need to be be able to auto-change the below RADIO button value, and I can't do that if both radio buttons have the same ID.

How should I properly manage this?

And while on this, I have the `required` field on both the YES and NO radio buttons.  Since radio buttons are only allow one selected value - is `required` needed on both or only one?

```
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="ceSiteBanner">
         <i id="ceAutoRegister_icon" class="iconRequired icon-information-outline"></i> Display Site Banner
         <i onclick="displayInfo('ceSiteBanner_Info');" class="iconMore icon-more"></i>
      </label>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
         <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ceSiteBanner" id="ceSiteBanner1" value="1" <?=$ceSiteBanner1?> required/>
            <span class="radio-icon"></span>
            <span class="form-check-description">Yes</span>
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
         <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ceSiteBanner" id="ceSiteBanner0" value="0" <?=$ceSiteBanner0?> required/>
            <span class="radio-icon"></span>
            <span class="form-check-description">No</span>
         </label>
      </div>
     </div>
```